# Understanding the order by clause used in SQL Injections

Tags: sql-injection

I am trying to enumerate a database, created specifically for the purpose of learning SQL injections. I am trying to discover the number of columns a particular select statement might be using. I do this by "Ordinal" ordering the result set. So, I start with ORDER BY 1, .. BY 2, and so on until I get an error returning 'Unknown column'. Now, for an injection like so:

`localhost/sqli?id=2' order by 7 AND  '1`

The resulting SQL statement is:

`mysql> SELECT * FROM table_name where id='2' order by 7 and '1';`

This returns a result set, but I was expecting it to throw an error returning `"unknown column '7' in 'order clause' ".` Why does it not throw the error. The table that I am working with has only 3 columns.

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't error out, but I think what you'd want to do is comment out the remainder so your order by is the last part of sql. I.e. `localhost/sqli?id=2' order by 7 --`

Comment: The scenario is that commenting out the rest of the SQL isn't an option. This is the video tutorial I am following - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0tyerVP9R98

Comment: Try running `EXPLAIN` on the query: `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table_name where id='2' order by 7 and '1';`

Comment: Running EXPLAIN on it returns - id 1, select_type SIMPLE, table table_name, type const, possible_keys PRIMARY, key PRIMARY, key_len 4, ref const, rows 1, Extra NULL. I am not sure what to make of the output.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the syntax of `ORDER BY` clause for the [`SELECT` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html), it states:

```
[ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
  [ASC | DESC], ...]
```

So you either specify a columns name (`col_name`), an expression (`expr`), or a column position (`position`), where column positions are integers.

Now if you compare this syntax with your `ORDER BY` clause:

```
… order by 7 and '1'
```

`7 and '1'` is an [expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/expressions.html), consisting of an `AND` operation with `7` and `'1'` as operands.

However, the following works as expected:

```
… order by 7, '1'
```

Where `7` is a column position and `'1'` is an expression.

Answer (score 1):

I think enumerating the number of columns is not what this is doing because for that we don't need a "'" in the order by injection as we don't want the application to throw an error except when the injection exceeds the number of columns in the original select statement. Moreover, I think you should use commenting out the rest of the statement after **order by**.